# Escape dollar sign in dollar-quoted strings query

Tags: cassandra, special-characters, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

Hello I am trying to work on a Cassandra query which has an explanation field of data type text. I am using `dollar-quoted strings` to escape special characters but I face problem when the string of my explanation field ends with a dollar sign

For example

```
INSERT INTO Users (name, explanation) VALUES ($$Tom$$, $$Some'text$$$);
```

The last two dollar-quoted strings are the end quotes but the third last is a part of the explanation, how can I escape that? Or is there any other way through  which I can escape all special characters including dollar sign?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [grammar](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/src/antlr/Lexer.g#L242), it looks like that the lexer is just search until the next occurrence of the `$$`, and doesn't distinguish between double & triple dollar signs.  But if you have any character after `$`, then it's just handled correctly (for example, string `$$dwewdewe'adqdq$'$$` works just fine) - it's only shouldn't be a last character before ending `$$`.  If you want to insert string with `'` character inside, you can just escape (see [doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/escape_char_r.html)) it with another `'` character (for example; `'this is string with '' inside'` - it works fine, and will produce `this is string with ' inside` as expected).

This is about inserting the statement one time.  But if you're inserting the data from your program, then it's better to use [prepared statements](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.10/manual/core/statements/prepared/) instead - they should be supported in all existing drivers.  When you're using prepared statements, you don't need to take care about escaping - it's the job of the driver (really, no escaping happens, as string is sent as-is, not as part of the statement).   And besides the lack of need for escaping, you also should get better performance, because parsing of the statement happens only once, when it's prepared, and then only statement ID plus parameters are sent to the Cassandra node.